# Retaining parameter types when using Objective-C block in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

I have just started implementing some of our new features in Swift rather than Objective-c, all ok so far but the one thing thats confusing me is how to properly use Obj-C blocks in Swift.

In my Obj-C class I have defined a block to be used to handle HTTP responses for calls to our API:

```
typedef void(^CCAPIClientRequestCompletionBlock)(id response, NSArray *messages, NSDictionary *metaData, NSError *error);
```

This is used in the following method:

```
-(void)createMeetingWithUsers:(NSArray *)users subject:(NSString *)subject andDescription:(NSString *)description withCompletionBlock:(CCAPIClientRequestCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```

I am now writing an API client to access a new are of our API in Swift and trying to reuse the block as a closure. The code below builds and runs:

```
apiClient.createMeeting(withUsers: userIds, subject: subject, andDescription: description) { (response, messages, metaData, error) -> Void in

    }
```

but I would like to be able to keep the parameter types and thought I should be able to do something like:

```
apiClient.createMeeting(withUsers: userIds, subject: subject, andDescription: description) { (response:Any?, messages:[Any], metaData:[AnyHashable:Any], error:NSError) -> Void in

    }
```

But when I try this, I get an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Any?, [Any], [AnyHashable : Any], NSError) -> Void' to expected argument type 'CCAPIClientRequestCompletionBlock!'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't have any nullability attributes declared but somehow you expected response to be optional. How's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should change all the types to optionals AND `NSError` to `Error?`:

```
apiClient.createMeeting(withUsers: userIds, subject: subject, andDescription: description) { (response:Any?, messages:[Any]?, metaData:[AnyHashable:Any]?, error:Error?) -> Void in 
   //TODO 
}
```

Comment: Swift will already treat them as unwrapped optionals. Try making them explicit e.g. apiClient.createMeeting(withUsers: userIds, subject: subject, andDescription: description) { (response:Any?, messages:[Any]!, metaData:[AnyHashable:Any]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    }

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Comment: Wait... no. That was the compiler leading me on. It still errors.

Comment: @darkbreed what do you mean by `it still errors`? Is it still the same error?

Comment: Yes, sorry - same error. It doesn't seem to care if they are optionals or explicit. I get the `Cannot convert value of type '(Any?, [Any], [AnyHashable : Any], NSError) -> Void' to expected argument type 'CCAPIClientRequestCompletionBlock!'` error regardless.